# Create table based upon numericInput and selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app that calculates drug rates based on dosages and mass for a veterinary clinic and then the tech can print the resulting table for a care sheet. I've seen where selectInput can be used to load a dataset and display it as a table, but I need to create the rates in the tables based upon the mass of the animal and drug concentration. For example, a drug may have a dosage of 1,2,3,4, or 5 mcg/kg/hr which can hopefully be loaded based upon the drug selected via selectInput, but I need the rate to be calculated by a formula (in this case (mass * dose)/concentration). This is further complicated by the fact that each drug has different dosages, so that also needs to be reactive based upon the selectInput.

What I have so far is below, but I haven't been able to get any tables to be produced that are responding to the data from the shiny app.

```
library(shiny)
drug.selections <- c("Fentanyl", "Ketamine", "Lidocaine", "Midazolam", "Metoclopramide", "Norepinephrine", "Dobutamine", 
                     "Dopamine", "Epinephrine", "Phenylephrine", "Propofol", "Dexmedetomidine 0.1 mg/dl", "Dexmedetomidine 0.5 mg/dl", "Diltiazem", "Furosemide", "Butorphanol",
                     "Hydromorphine", "Morphine", "Methadone", "ACA", "Magnesium", "Alfaxalone") 
drug.selections <- sort(drug.selections)
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Continuous Rate Infusion"
  ),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("name", "Pet Name"),
      numericInput("mass", "Pet Weight (kg)", value = 0, min =0, max = 200),
      selectInput("drug", "Drug", drug.selections), 
      numericInput("concentration", "Concentration", value = 0, min = 0, max = 500),
      numericInput("time", "How many hours needed", value = 0, min = 0, max = 40),
      checkboxInput("dilute", "Dilute?", value = FALSE) 
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Dose", tableOutput("dose")),
                  tabPanel("Diluted Dose", tableOutput("ddose")),
                  tabPanel("Dilution Recipe", tableOutput("recipe")),
                  tabPanel("Summary", textOutput("summary")),
                  textOutput("name"), 
                  textOutput("mass"),
                  textOutput("drug")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mass <- reactive({
    get(input$mass, inherits = FALSE)
  })


  output$summary <- renderText({
    paste (input$name, "weighs", input$mass, "kg and is on", input$concentration, "of", input$drug)
  })

  output$dose <- renderTable({
    dose
  })

  output$ddose <- renderTable({
    ddose
  })

  output$recipe <- renderTable({
    recipe
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to get the "Dose" tab to produce a table of the dose and rate. Pretty sure I can do something similar for the other tabs. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the comment on my previous answer, I have added some data on each drug which might represent the different doses for each drug.

So now, when drug is selected, the calculations are performed on ALL the predefined dosages for that drug, in this block below

```
output$dose <- renderTable({

    dose = dosage_table[, input$drug]

    rate = dose *  as.numeric(input$mass) / as.numeric(input$concentration)

    data.frame(Dose = dose, Rate = rate)


  })
```

## Final Code

## UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Continuous Rate Infusion"
  ),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # add dosage
      textInput("name", "Pet Name"),
      numericInput("mass", "Pet Weight (kg)", value = 0, min =0, max = 200),
      selectInput("drug", "Drug", drug.selections), 
      numericInput("concentration", "Concentration", value = 0, min = 0, max = 500),
      numericInput("time", "How many hours needed", value = 0, min = 0, max = 40),
      checkboxInput("dilute", "Dilute?", value = FALSE) 
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Dose", tableOutput("dose")),
                  tabPanel("Diluted Dose", tableOutput("ddose")),
                  tabPanel("Dilution Recipe", tableOutput("recipe")),
                  tabPanel("Summary", textOutput("summary")),
                  textOutput("name"), 
                  textOutput("mass"),
                  textOutput("drug")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

## Server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dosage_table <- data.frame('Fentanyl' = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
                             'Ketamine' = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),
                             "Lidocaine" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Midazolam" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Metoclopramide" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Norepinephrine" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Dobutamine" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Dopamine" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Epinephrine" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Phenylephrine" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Propofol" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Dexmedetomidine 0.1 mg/dl" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Dexmedetomidine 0.5 mg/dl" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Diltiazem" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Furosemide" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Butorphanol" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),
                             "Hydromorphine" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Morphine" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Methadone" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "ACA" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Magnesium" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), 
                             "Alfaxalone" = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5))

  mass <- reactive({
    get(input$mass, inherits = FALSE)
  })


  output$summary <- renderText({
    paste (input$name, "weighs", input$mass, "kg and is on", input$concentration, "of", input$drug)
  })

  output$dose <- renderTable({

    dose = dosage_table[, input$drug]

    rate = dose *  as.numeric(input$mass) / as.numeric(input$concentration)

    data.frame(Dose = dose, Rate = rate)


  })

  output$ddose <- renderTable({
    ddose
  })

  output$recipe <- renderTable({
    recipe
  })
}

# App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't exactly what I am looking for. I know there isn't a table "dose" yet, that is what I want to create. The veterinarians aren't comfortable with the technicians inputing the dosages, so that can't come from a numeric input. The dosage should come from the drug selected. But this is complicated a bit as different drugs have different dosages. For example, Fentanyl has dosages of: c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), but Ketamine dosages should be c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5). The rates corresponding to each of those dosages need to be calculated and all of it should be represented in a table

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I should have made it clearer that it would be easier to solve your problem if some dose data was included. Let me know if the updated Answer is more along the lines of what you are meaning.